# Can't install any version of Visual Studio on win 10

Tags: visual-studio, windows-10, failed-installation

So as I mentioned, I'm running windows 10.

When I first installed windows 10, visual studio community 2015 installed just fine. Then the licence expired so I wanted to reinstall it.
The installation just stops randomly... that it is stuck one one thing..
I also spotted a little connection between the bar saying 'Acquiring' and the second bar.. when the first bar is full, the installation gets stuck on installation of one current installing thing.

I don't know how to explain it though. It just never happened to me.
A screenshot wouldn't help and a video would be too long and boring.

I can't really tell if it is installing anything or not... I once let it install whole one day and it was stuck at the same thing that it was when I left home...

Is there any good explaination and or fix for that?

Comment: The license expired and you can simply log in to Visual Studio with your Microsoft account to renew it, not reinstalling it. Right now, you probably only have to try this, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/mats/program_install_and_uninstall?wa=wsignin1.0

Comment: Can't anymore.. I uninstalled all the studios that I installed... but I can't install it.... the uninstallation had problems with redistributables... So I uninstalled them and ran the uninstallation again and then it uninstalled with no problems

Comment: But now, I can't uninstall ANY version of the program on Windows 10.. I could when I first installed windows 10....

Comment: I can't *install ANY version of the program

Comment: It actually gets stuck when it's supposed to install Microsoft Build Tools 14.0 (x86)..
It just won't complete.. and when I let it install a little longer, an error shows up with now specific error code. I will post a logfile soon if I'll be able to.

Comment: Ok so I was browsing the internet a little.. I found out that it might be the windows defender keeping msi installators from installing.. but I don't know how to disable that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution for this problem!
I had to disable Windows Defender, because it was blocking the installation..
It was keeping the installation from running msi files.

To disable Windows Defender, follow the steps on this page: http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5918-windows-defender-turn-off-windows-10-a.html

Now the installation doesn't stop/isn't stuck on installing one thing :).

I hope I also helped the others that had the same problem before!

Comment: It would be surprising to see this is the cause, as many guys like me do not disable it to have something installed. Well, hope Microsoft can track it down and solve it.